# Unmarshal JSON Array into JSON Object

Tags: json, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm trying to work with an API that returns JSON data. Nested within the JSON is an array of Objects. The data is structured, and I'm trying to convert that array into an Object, but I'm coming up empty handed.

In other words, I have this:

```
{
  "summary": {
    "distances": [
      {
        "activity": "total",
        "distance": 2.83
      },
      {
        "activity": "tracked",
        "distance": 2.83
      },
      { ... },
      { ... },
      { ... },
      { ... },
      { ... }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I'd like to have something like this:

```
  "summary": {
    "distances": {
       "total": 2.83,
       "tracked": 2.83,
       ...
    ]
  }
}
```

I have written code that unmarshalls the JSON, but it only works if the format of the struct is the same as the JSON: https://play.golang.org/p/jsu_Ym8kRQd

Comment: That's not called unmarshaling, that's called converting (although if you want to do it in Go, it will involve both unmarshaling and marshaling)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want using the standard library JSON package. I am not aware of any third-party JSON unmarshaler that can do this. You have to unmarshal the JSON to an intermediate structure that matches your input, and then convert that to the structure you need. If the structure of the `distances` is the same for all elements, and if you're trying to convert that input JSON to the output JSON you want, you can do that with a simple structure, like this:

```
type Result struct {
  Distances map[string]float64
}

func process(input []byte) Result {
  var data InputStruct
  json.Unmarshal(input,&data)
  dest:=Result{Distances:make(map[string]float64)}
  for _,dist:=range data.Distances {
     dest.Distances[dist.Activity]=dist.Distance 
  }
  return dest
}
```